# How do I stop the code from running after showing a dialoge? (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, dialog

At the very start of my application I have a dialoge appear where the user can select between two options:

[image]

The code from where I run the dialoge looks like this:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    popup.show(supportFragmentManager, "example d")
    Log.d("TAG", "THIS SHOULD BE RUN AFTER I HAVE CLICKED ONE OF THE DIALOGUE BUTTONS")

    checkSharedPreference()
    switcher()
}
```

The problem is that the code doesn't stop by `popup.show(supportFragmentManager, "example d")`. It keeps running. I assume that this has to do with dialoge being async, no? How do I solve this? `Completionhandler`? `Asynctask`? Something else?

***UPDATE***
I tried building the clock in accordance with what @Akshay Paliwal said:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    public fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

    val context = applicationContext
    val sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(applicationContext)

    builder.setTitle("Välkommen till Demensvård utan tvång.")
            .setMessage("Berätta vem du är.")
            .setPositiveButton("Anhörig") { dialog, which ->
                val version = "anhorig"
                sharedPreference.edit().putString("version", version).apply()
                checkSharedPreference()
                switcher()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Personal") { dialog, which ->
                val version = "personal"
                sharedPreference.edit().putString("version", version).apply()
                checkSharedPreference()
                switcher()
            }

    return builder.create()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    //THIS? doesn't work...
    onCreateDialog(WHAT BUNDLE???)

    //OR THIS?
    onCreateDialog(what bundle?).show(supportFragmentManager, "example d")
}

How do I call the `onCreateDialog` function? `onCreateDialog(WHAT BUNDLE???)` what bundle should be passed? `onCreateDialog(what bundle?).show(supportFragmentManager, "example d")` Again what bundle?
```

Or do I need to have `onCreateDialog` in a separate class that extends `AppCompatDialogFragment`? In that case do I call `main.switcher` from the callback in that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dialog callback for this purpose as below:

1. Create a dialog or alert dialog
2. receive callback on action on buttons

   ```
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
       builder.setMessage("message")
               .setTitle("Warning");
       builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

               dialogInterface.dismiss();
               // do your go ahead task here like
               //checkSharedPreference()
               //switcher()

           }
       });
       builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.update_linkedin_app_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               dialogInterface.dismiss();
               finish(); // to finish current activity
           }
       });
       builder.create().show();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the good reply. I have some problems calling the method correctly. See update in my post.

Comment: Got it to work now thanks to your post @Akshay :) I was confused at first since I had the dialog builder in a separate class which didn't work at all :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the popup is a non blocking one. As far as I know Android was designed to prevent developers from writing synchronous dialogs.

What you can do here is to add a callback to your popup and handle the response in the respective listener method. Move the code from the onStart() to your handler method and then it will be executed after your popup responds.

In the following sample, you would add a listener to one of the popups buttons and execute the code in its onClick() method:

```
popupButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener();
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
   Log.d("TAG", "THIS SHOULD BE RUN AFTER I HAVE CLICKED ONE OF THE DIALOGUE BUTTONS")
 } });
```